# Can I assume the highest auto increment value is always the newest entry?

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

I have the following code to get the newest entry from the a table.

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database);
$result = $con->query("SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Samples");
$newest = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

The field `ID` is the primary key and has auto_increment. I have no code to alter the value of `ID`.

The code always successfully yields the newest entry when I test it, but I don't know if this is behavior I can rely on. Will this always work? If not, is there a more reliable way to get the newest entry?

Comment: the answer is yes.

Comment: it's mostly true, but not *always* because of some edge cases... I'm specifically thinking MyISAM special handling of AUTO_INCREMENT for groups when the autoinc column is not the first column in the index. Also innodb_autoinc_lock_mode can influence behavior with multiple concurrent sessions, and there is nothing that prevents a statement from providing a value for an AUTO_INCREMENT column (a value is automatically assigned  when no value is provided, or a NULL value or a 0 value is provided. (Do NOT rely on `MAX(id)` to get the auto_increment value for an immediately preceding INSERT.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM ...` always work?

**No, it will not.** If you have more than one copy of your program connected to your database, and one program does what you suggest, and another program then performs an insert, the first program's `MAX(ID)` value will become stale. It's a race condition. Those are very difficult to detect and debug, because they don't crop up until a system is under heavy load.

If all you care about is a snapshot of `MAX(ID)` you'll be OK. But you cannot use this `MAX(ID)` value as the value for the next insertion, unless you *never* will have more than one program instance inserting data. It's unwise to rely on that kind of *never.*

> If not, is there a more reliable way to get the newest entry?

Immediately after you do an INSERT operation you can do `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` to retrieve the autoincrementing ID just used. Various APIs, like `mysqli`, `PDO`, and `JDBC` return this ID to a calling program when an INSERT operation completes.

[`LAST_INSERT_ID()` and the related API functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) work on a connection-by-connection basis. Therefore, if multiple connections are inserting rows, each connection will get its own id values.

Comment: To add to this, there is also the possibility that the last two entries came from two different transactions. One could have "reserved" earlier id "slots" by but finished later... which introduces the need to define what one means by "newest".

Comment: It's not clear from the question that he wants to get the ID of the row that was just inserted, or just wants to get the most recent ID in general.

Comment: @Barmar I should have made that clear. I want the ID of a row I just inserted.

Comment: @SarcasticSully Then `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is indeed the way to do it. It's also available as `$con->insert_id`.

Comment: @Barmar and those both return the ID of the last thing inserted by `$con`, even if some other connection has inserted something since?

Comment: @SarcasticSully Yes. From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id): The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client.

Answer (score -1):

MySQL has an auto increment functionality, you can set a column to auto-increment using

```
ALTER TABLE document MODIFY COLUMN ID INT auto_increment
```

Then you can add entries to the table, without worrying about the Id, using max can be problematic especially when data can be modifies outside the system you are building, say by direct entry to the table. To insert a record, leave the Id as a null.

I hope this helps, cheers!